# How to search for a particular answer using keyword?

Tags: support, answered-questions, searching

I had posted above 500 answers. From that I want to search for a particular answer using keywords.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
user:202806 is:a [tag] keywords
```

or just:

```
user:202806 is:a keywords
```

More info [in the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching).

Comment: In case we cant remember our barcode we can just use `user:me` ;)

Comment: @Takkat Ooh, that's even fancier! Didn't know about that one :D